# Jetpack Compose preview not showing. IllegalArgumentException: createMdcTheme requires the host context's theme to extend Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Compose preview is not showing with error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: createMdcTheme requires the host context's theme to extend Theme.MaterialComponents
```

I am using [Splash Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen) for app's startup theming. After splash is gone, app theme changes to "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar".

I am suspicious that preview is not compatible with splash api?